# Importing comparison function from another module for React.memo

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created utility comparison function to use inside the `React.memo()`.

```
export const propsComparator =
  <Props extends object>(
    shallowComparisonProps: Array<keyof Props>, 
    deepComparisonProps: Array<keyof Props>
  ) =>
  (oldProps: Props, newProps: Props): boolean => {
    const shallowEquality = shallowComparisonProps.every((prop) => 
      oldProps[prop] === newProps[prop]
    );
    if (!shallowEquality) {
      return false;
    }
    return deepComparisonProps.every((prop) => 
      JSON.stringify(oldProps[prop]) === JSON.stringify(newProps[prop])
    );
  };
```

Then I imported it into my component's module and used it for the purpose it was intended.

```
import { propsComparator } from 'utils';

const MyComponent: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return <>...</>;
}

export default memo(
  MyComponent,
  propsComparator<Props>(
    ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'],
    ['prop4', 'prop5'],
  ),
);
```

Then I receive an error in the browser's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.propsComparator) is not a function
```

I tried to `console.log(propsComparator)` before the MyComponent's export and it was `undefined`.

**Question:** How to avoid this error and make memoization work?